# Why this ArrayList object gets blank at a certain point of the code?

Tags: android, arraylist

```
public List<String> itemLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

`itemLists` takes values inside `.addOnSuccessListener` (see *tagg1*, *tagg2*, *tagg3*). But, when out of `.addOnSuccessListener`, it seems that becomes blank (see *tagg4*).

How is it possible? Why does it happen?

According to me, it is because *tagg4* is printed before `.addOnSuccessListener` run. Indeed, from `Logcat` timestamp it seems this. If this is the reason, why *tagg4* is printed before `.addOnSuccessListener` run? In the code, it is after.

**Java**

```
public void searchTags() {
        mRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            Store store = documentSnapshot.toObject(Store.class);
                            for (String tag : store.getTags()) {
                                itemLists.add(tag);
                                Log.d("tagg1", itemLists.toString());
                            }
                            Log.d("tagg2", itemLists.toString());
                        }
                        Log.d("tagg3", itemLists.toString());
                    }
                });
        Log.d("tagg4", itemLists.toString());
        return;
    }
```

**Logcat**

```
04-07 10:52:27.080 15268-15268/com.example.ves.gennaio3 D/tagg4: []
04-07 10:52:27.132 15268-15268/com.example.ves.gennaio3 D/tagg1: [nome]
    [nome, indirizzo]
    [nome, indirizzo, numero]
04-07 10:52:27.132 15268-15268/com.example.ves.gennaio3 D/tagg2: [nome, indirizzo, numero]
04-07 10:52:27.132 15268-15268/com.example.ves.gennaio3 D/tagg3: [nome, indirizzo, numero]
```

Comment: Because the success listener is a callback, which means tag4 can be called before the listener is called back. It isn't a problem, it's by design

Answer (score 0):

The code in the `onSuccessListener` is not executed immediately. Rather, it's what's known as a callback - it defines what the progam should do when a certain thing happens later. In this specific situation, the body of `onSuccess` is executed when the asynchronous method `get()` completes successfully (I'm assuming from context here, I don't really know what `mRef` is or what the `get()` method does). So your sequence of events goes like this:

1) initiate the asynchronous `get()` method and define what to do when it completes successfully

2) log `tagg4`

3) `get()` completes successfully, fires the callback and add items to your list

Answer (score 0):

Actually, here, in this case, you have addOnSuccessListener, this will listen to the change of events and if anything changes then it will call onSuccess and then only the code inside onSuccess will run. And the tagg4 is outside of onSuccess so in java code is executed line by line and it is doing like that and the rest code inside the onSuccess is executed only when there is a call inside the listener.

First of all your item list is empty and when the listener addOnSuccessListener get a call inside its callback function onSuccess the data is stored in itemLists and then only they have values you see in Logcat.